# How to validate user input with numbers 0-9 and letters a-z and A-Z in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I am working on a project that must allow combination of numbers (0-9), characters (a -z and A-Z) and minimum length should be 8. I tried a lot, but I could not get a good solution.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.newPasswordFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      newPassword: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8),
        Validators.pattern('^A-Za-z0-9')])],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
    }, {
      validator: MustMatch('newPassword', 'confirmPassword')
  });
  }


<form [formGroup]="newPasswordFormGroup" role="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitPassword()">
                <div class="form-group text-left">
                    <input type="password" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.newPassword.errors }" formControlName="newPassword" class="form-control input-underline input-lg textBox" id="newPassword" placeholder="Enter new password" />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.newPassword.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.newPassword.errors.required">New password is required</div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.newPassword.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.newPassword.errors.pattern">#Password should be a minimum of 8 characters and contain a combination of letters and numbers</div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.newPassword.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.newPassword.errors.minlength">Password should be a minimum of 8 characters</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-left">
                    <input type="password" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.confirmPassword.errors }" formControlName="confirmPassword" class="form-control input-underline input-lg textBox" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Enter confirm password" />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.confirmPassword.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.confirmPassword.errors.required">Confirm password is required</div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.confirmPassword.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.confirmPassword.errors.mustMatch">Passwords must match</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="password-btn">
                    <button type="submit" [disabled]="isDisabled" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn"> Submit </button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Ex: 
   It should be "s12sre34"

Comment: Pattern should be `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$`, which means "letters and figures, minimum eight times, from start to finish"

Comment: i am trying this pattern

Comment: if i enter 12345678, it accepts, i need combination of numbers and letters. It should be  "s12sre34"

Comment: `must allow combination of numbers(0-9), characters(a -z and A-Z) and Minimum length should be 8`. Next time be more specific ... Anyway, you can use [negative lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did like this. it worked for me.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.newPasswordFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      newPassword: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8),
        CustomValidator.findCombinationLettersAndNumbers()])],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
    }, {
      validator: MustMatch('newPassword', 'confirmPassword')
  });
  }


 import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

 export class CustomValidator {


    public static findCombinationLettersAndNumbers(): ValidatorFn {

        return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
            // console.log('val:', c.value);

            let isDigit = false;
            let isCapsOrSmallLetter = false;
            // let isSmallLetter = false;
            let isSpecialChar = false;
            if ((!/\d/.test(c.value))) {
                // console.log('password must contain digits');
                isDigit = false;
            } else {
                isDigit = true;
            }
            if (!/[A-Za-z]/.test(c.value)) {
                // console.log('password must contain uppercase letter');
                isCapsOrSmallLetter = false;
            } else {
                isCapsOrSmallLetter = true;
            }
            // if (!/[a-z]/.test(c.value)) {
            //     console.log('password must contain lowercase letter');
            //     isSmallLetter = false;
            // } else {
            //     isSmallLetter = true;
            // }

            if (!/[ !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/.test(c.value)) {
                // console.log('password must contain special character');
                isSpecialChar = true;
            }

            if (isDigit && isCapsOrSmallLetter && isSpecialChar === true) {
                // null is required here. otherwise form wonot submit.
                return null;
            }
            return { passwordval: true };

        };

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the validator `Validators.pattern('(?=(?:\d*[A-Za-z]){1,})(?=(?:[A-Za-z]*\d){1,})[A-Za-z\d]{8}')])`

Explanation:

```
(?=(?:\d*[A-Z]){1,})(?=(?:[A-Z]*\d){1,})[A-Za-z\d]{8}
```

- `(?=(?:\d*[A-Za-z]){1,})` positive lookahead of non-capturing group matching a [digit-then-letter] pattern happening 1 or more times
- `(?=(?:[A-Za-z]*\d){1,})` positive lookahead of non-capturing group matching a [letter-then-digit] pattern happening 1 or more times
- `[A-Za-z\d]{8}` match eight digits or letters so length is correct

---

- *note 1:* `A-Za-z` can just be `A-Z` if you ignore case
- *note 2:* `\d` is the same as `0-9` in other examples

Comment: can you please explain me ? how should i input ?

Comment: you have `Validators.pattern('^A-Za-z0-9')` and you can just replace it with `Validators.pattern('(?=(?:\d*[A-Za-z]){1,})(?=(?:[A-Za-z]*\d){1,})[A-Za-z\d]{8}')])`

Comment: i gave input in the text box. " ii89ii898kk89" . it is not working in angular 7. can you please help me with it ?